# what does the word "transform" mean in tf?

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and as a result was reading about the tf package. I read this paper: http://wiki.ros.org/Papers/TePRA2013_Foote?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=TePRA2013_Foote.pdf;  where the author made statements such as "...The  request  is  the  same  in  every case, and the programmer only needs to know the coordinate frames in which they want to operate and those relevant to the task, as long as the system knows the intermediate frames and can compute the resultant transforms.", another one  is "The tf library can be separated into two different parts. The first  part  is  disseminating  transform  information  to  the  entire system. The second part of the library receives the transform  information  and  stores  it  for  later  use".

I do not understand the context in which this word is used. My understanding of the word transform is synonymous to the word 'change'. Can you please help me understand the context in which this word is used? I do not understand what "transform information" means, and all other uses of this word in this document. Thanks for your help... this will help me better understand the package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272400/what-does-the-word-%22transform%22-mean-in-tf?/) by [BuilderMike](https://answers.ros.org/users/31958/buildermike/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2017-10-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andymcevoy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1860/andymcevoy/) on 2017-10-05**:
Is [section 6.2](http://elvis.rowan.edu/%7Ekay/papers/kinematics.pdf) like something you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The author is referring to *coordinate transformations*, the mathematical concept.

See (random internet link) [Coordinate Transformations](http://www.continuummechanics.org/coordxforms.html) for instance.

`tf` is a library that makes handling such transforms in the context of robotics applications in ROS almost trivial, hence the popularity of it (and many references to it) in ROS.

From the [wiki/tf2](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2) page:

> tf2 is the second generation of the transform library, which lets the user keep track of multiple coordinate frames over time. tf2 maintains the relationship between coordinate frames in a tree structure buffered in time, and lets the user transform points, vectors, etc between any two coordinate frames at any desired point in time.

And see #q270403 for a related question.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BuilderMike](https://answers.ros.org/users/31958/buildermike/) on 2017-10-06**:
thanks for this answer. I now understand. thanks.